# Rails 4.2 MySQL 5.6 Elastic Beanstalk YAML Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, yaml, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

So I am trying to deploy a ruby on rails app to Amazon AWS Elastic Beanstalk. There are no errors in the terminal but the app won't deploy. When I check the log there are two errors being shown

`Activity execution failed, because: command failed with error code 1: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/12_db_migration.sh`

And below that...

```
YAML syntax error occurred while parsing /var/app/ondeck/config/database.yml. Please note that YAML must be consistently indented using spaces. Tabs are not allowed. Error: (<unknown>): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 21 column 3

Psych::SyntaxError: (<unknown>): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 21 column 3

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => db:load_config
```

I have checked my database.yml file over and over again for errors but don't see anything here it is

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: sean
  password: "mypass"
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
  database: reviewchipWebsite_development

test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: sean
  password: "mypass"
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
  database: reviewchipWebsite_test

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: ebdb
  username: seanAndrew
  password: "mypass"
  host: aa1bszpu5vavup2.cvln1rz36k57.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com
  port: 3306
  socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Comment: YAML is very picky, you might have some non-printed characters (like additional line breaks). Try to copy-paste your database.yml here http://www.yamllint.com, it'll clean it up.

Comment: Awesome! I'll put my comment as an answer, if you don't mind :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YAML is very picky, you might have some non-printed characters (like additional line breaks). Try to copy-paste your database.yml here [yamllint.com](http://yamllint.com), it'll clean it up.